# Mysql GROUP_CONCAT ORDER BY on combined fields

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I'm using GROUP_CONCAT to build up Quartiles and am unsure how to get it working on scores created from two columns.

My GROUP_CONCAT looks like this - but at the moment is ordering on 'gst.raw_gps' when it should be ordering on the values arrived at through '(100/gst.max_gps)*gst.raw_gps'

```
GROUP_CONCAT(       
    (100/gst.max_gps)*gst.raw_gps
    ORDER BY gst.raw_gps
    SEPARATOR ','
)
```

Any advice much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Then use the expression instead of the column name:

```
GROUP_CONCAT((100/gst.max_gps)*gst.raw_gps
             ORDER BY (100/gst.max_gps)*gst.raw_gps
             SEPARATOR ','
            )
```